# Zabbix notification to MS Teams

Tags: notifications, office365, microsoft-teams, zabbix

I have zabbix on virtual machine Cent OS. Zabbix is configured to access only from the internal network https://192.168.42.13
Server Cent OS has access to the internet.
I download from Office365 MS Teams connector configuration for zabbix. Made all settings in zabbix, but did not get any notification in MS Teams.
Is this problem because zabbix is configured to access only the internal network? If yes, how make this notification without opening zabbix front end to the internet?

Comment: No, that should not be the problem. Have you configured the notification chanel+notifications correctly to go to Teams in Zabbix?

Comment: Could you please make sure the URL you provided is a correct IP address, a fully qualified domain name or localhost? Please refer: https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/msteams

Answer (score 0):

Mimic the same process that is followed to enable/send zabbix notifications to slack.

Enable an incoming webhook to your MS Teams channel.

Use that incoming webhook and creat Ms teams media type on your zabbix server. Mimic the javascript in slack media type, it should work

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide logs or information about error on that but I also had issues with teams webhook few weeks ago.
Last time microsoft changed URI for webhook and there is required small change in zabbix script for that (if you didn't do that yet).

Administration -> media type -> MS Teams -> script:

there you have to check if you have proper check:

```
if (!params.teams_endpoint) {
    throw 'Cannot get teams_endpoint';
}
else if (!params.teams_endpoint.includes('office.com/webhook')) {
    throw 'Invalid MS Teams webhook URL: ' + params.teams_endpoint;
}
```

that change in "else if" helped for me